# parse error syntax error unexpected token on simple AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parse-error

Im a beginner in AJAX & javascript, so please bear with me.

I want to pass a variable (`document.getElementById('txtSearch').value`) from my AJAX to a PHP so i tried to code something like this :

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function() {
            var keyword = "";
            alert(document.getElementById('txtSearch').value);
            $.ajax({
                url: BASE_URL + 'index.php/jwm/search', //This is the current doc
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'json', // add json datatype to get json
                data: ({keyword: document.getElementById('txtSearch').value}),
                error : function(jq, st, err) {
                    console.log(arguments);
                    alert(st + " : " + err);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });  
        });
```

However, i got an error : `parse error syntax error unexpected token <` and sometimes the error change a little bit to be like this : `parse error syntax error unexpected token T`.

**EDIT**
This is my PHP code :

```
function search() {
        $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
        echo "TEST : $keyword";
        $result = $this->jwm_m->getDataByKeyword('msmall', $keyword);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');  
        header('Content-type: application/json', true);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

This is what my console get :

```
arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
```

**My goal is to passing** `document.getElementById('txtSearch').value`, please help me out.

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: is your php script actually returning a valid json file ?

Comment: Inspect the response in your Developer Tools Network Panel. The parse error usually means there's an error in the backend and it's not returning proper JSON back to you.

Comment: Did you able to get `document.getElementById('txtSearch')` any result for this line try to execute in console

Comment: As a matter of fact, adding on to @godfrzero:
Is the function you defined called `search()` being called when you make that AJAX call? Does it work when you go to that URL directly?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to note about your updated question, in the PHP code:

- You mentioned that you get an error `parse error syntax error unexpected token T`. This is probably because of the `echo "TEST : $keyword";` in PHP, which causes the response to be invalid JSON.
- You're setting the headers after `echo "TEST : $keyword";`, this will throw a PHP warning similar to `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...`

So remove the `echo "TEST : $keyword";` line and try sending the request again. This time, keep the network panel of your developer tools open and check the data being sent/received. If you're still having issues, update your question with the server response & request body. The more information you provide, the more likely it is that you'll get a good solution.